# Pass a configuration file during scada-lts when launching a container

Tags: docker, scadalts

I'm using docker-compose to spin up 3 containers: a mysql database, scada-lts and openplc. I've created a docker volume for openplc to add a structured text file so the plc is ready to go. I'd like to launch the scada-lts container and load the configuration at the same, rather than having to go through the process of importing the zip file. Does anyone know of a way to do this?